# How do I access Ember Route variables in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've noticed something interesting today.

If I create a variable in my Controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   controllerFoo: "Cut"
});
```

And I create a similar variable in my Route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    routeFoo: "Copy"
});
```

that when I print it in the .hbs:

```
controllerFoo:{{controllerFoo}}
<hr>
routeFoo: {{routeFoo}}
```

only the controllerFoo will display. I thought that Route and Controller variables could be used interchangeably. If I wanted to use a route variable, how could I do that? Or maybe is it bad practice?

Comment: template context is controller, by default whateever you return from model hook will be set as `model` property in controller, if you want anything other than that you need to use setupController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template context is controller, so mostly state will be maintained by the controller. If in case you need to pass some property from route to template then you need to use `model` hook of the Route or use `setupController` hook of the Route and set the required properties in controller.